# How do props.children get passed between different components?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm going through a React course on udemy.  The creator of the video has his code set up this way.
[code setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PL3Z.png).

I am confused as to why this works. To me, I am creating a page component with the prop of title and the children of h2, and three p's.  In the page component, I return a container component with {props.children} between the two tags.  The container component then returns {props.children} between the div.

Why is the props.children the same props.children?  I would think that it is the props.children of the original props.children, because the container is passed props.children as the props parameter.

This is obviously not the case my content gets displayed with the h2, and three p's between a div.

Comment: *I would think that it is the props.children of the original props.children, because the container is passed props.children as the props parameter.* - what?

Comment: Please don't describe the code in sentences. It's very ambiguous and hard to understand. Can you please show us what you mean in code (I want to see what you are trying to do and what you expect to see)?

Comment: the container component takes a parameter of props.  So I'm thinking it looks like this:
```Container(props.children)   {
return (
    <div
      className={"container py-md-5 " + (props.wide ? "" : "container--narrow")}
    >
     **{props.children.children}**
    </div>
  );
}```

Comment: the container component takes a parameter of props.  So I'm thinking it would work like this:
```
Container(props.children)   {
return (
    <div
      className={"container py-md-5 " + (props.wide ? "" : "container--narrow")}
    >
     **{props.children.children}**
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with a slightly different case then work towards yours. Suppose i'm just passing a string using a standard prop (ie, not the children prop):

```
function About() {
  return <Page title="About Us"/>
}
function Page(props) {
  return <Container title={props.title} />
}
function Container(props) {
  return <div>{props.title}</div>
}
```

`About` creates a `<Page>`, and gives it a `title` prop, with the value "About Us". In `Page`, props is an object that looks like `{ title: "About Us" }`. Page then creates a `<Container>` with a `title` prop and it gets the value of the title from `props.title`, which is "About Us", Finally, `Container` gets a props object that also looks like `{ title: "About Us" }`, and uses that to create a `<div>`.

Next i'll rename that prop to be called `children` instead of `title`.

```
function About() {
  return <Page children="About Us"/>
}
function Page(props) {
  return <Container children={props.children} />
}
function Container(props) {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>
}
```

This code will do the same thing, just the prop has a different name. The string is still being handed off from one component to the next.

You might not be used to seeing `children` written as an explicit prop like this, but it's supported. `children` does have a special ability that you can put it into the child position instead, and that's how people usually use it. That's shown in the next example, but note that the follow code does exactly the same thing as the previous code:

```
function About() {
  return <Page>About Us</Page>
}
function Page(props) {
  return <Container>{props.children}</Container>
}
function Container(props) {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>
}
```

And finally, to make it more like your original question, instead of passing in a string we can pass in some JSX elements.

```
function About() {
  return (
    <Page>
      <h2>About Us</h2>
      <p /* ... etc */ />
      <p /* ... etc */ />
    </Page>
  )
}
function Page(props) {
  return <Container>{props.children}</Container>
}
function Container(props) {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>
}
```

This does the same thing as the last one, except that instead of a string being forward along, it's an array of objects that are being forwarded along (that array of objects describes the h2, p, and p).

Comment: First off, thanks so much for taking the time to write to such a thorough answer!

I think I just had my a-ha! moment reading your response.

By placing the {props.children} object between the Container tags, it makes that a child of Container.  By making it a child of Container, it can then be accessed using {props.children} in the Container component.

Thank you so much! My brain has been struggling with this for some time now.